# How to screenscrape my youtube video feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, screen-scraping, nokogiri

1. How to get the feed of my account? (Or how can I sign in my account when using Nokogiri?)
2. What would be a good solution to get the video from various video channels?(So I can avoid signing in my account in problem1) 
   Specifically, how to deal with pagination?
3. The videos screenscraped may not be all needed. How can I make a pre-save page to cancel out the videos that I don't want? i.e. create a editing interface for screenscraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube has a developers API from which all this should be available. Have you checked it out? See:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/